# .htaccess Redirect and proxy ports

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, proxy, port

I have an apache server that is part of a cloud servers network.
The virtual server its configured to respond at port 9000, but you access from outside through port 80. Thats working fine, except for when I try to make a redirect from the .htaccess file

I have the next 2 lines to redirect errors to a folder index

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule .* /folder/ [R=301,L]
```

That tries to redirect the user to:
www.domain.com:9000/folder/, and it should be redirecting to www.domain.com/folder (which means, www.domain.com:80)

How can I avoid that?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it changing the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer - yes you can't redirect to a different domain/port without using an absolute uri in your rewrite rule